# Ubuntu One v2 for Windows doesn't install or run properly

Tags: ubuntu-one, windows-7

I had the Beta 1 installed on Windows 7, downloaded v2 and

- It doesn't install properly as there's no way of UNINSTALLING it in
  Control Panel
- It won't synchronise nor start up at startup.
- When I click on the icon it starts OK giving me the normal dialog box
  but I also get a huge pop-up full of gibberish. Here is a screenshot:

  [image]
- It also says that syncing is up to date when it plainly isn't - I
  saved a file to my Ubuntu One folder in Windows today and the version
  on my Ubuntu One web page is still showing the previous one from four
  weeks ago...

So how do I either completely uninstall, or fix this?

Comment: Please add the image directly, also your link doesn't work - says page not found.

Comment: Link works fine here....(I can't add an image - it's my first post...)

Comment: I think you have to make the image publicly viewable. Since you are  logged into your Google Account, you are able to view it, but we can't.

Comment: Ah sorry - you should be able to see it now!

Comment: No problemo, you are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, that looks like you are getting a 500 error from the ubuntu one server when trying to retrieve your account information (let it be account info, which devices you have, or shares and folders).

I'd say we should file two different bugs for this issue:

1. That dialog is a horrible user experience.
2. We should take a look of why your are getting that 500.

I have filled [bug 1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-control-panel/+bug/862540) but I cannot fill bug 2 for you. Can you please go to the [bugs page](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-control-panel/)  and explain the steps you followed and zip the folder in C:\Users\%your_user%\AppData\Local\xdg

Please do make sure that you mark the bug as private until we make sure that there is no important data there.

Comment: I can't see anywhere to mark the bug private....

Comment: OK - found how to mark it as private. NOT obvious! Here's the bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-control-panel/+bug/862638

Comment: OK the pop-up's been fixed (thanks!) - but it's STILL not synchronising AT ALL....even though it says it is...

Comment: Can you snd a bug report with the logs saying that it does not sync?